# Is there any way to shift row values in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift values of row 10 , Fintech into next column and fill the city column in same row with Bahamas. Is there any way to do that?
[image]

I found the `dataframe.shift()`  function of pandas but it is limited to columns and it shifts all the values.

Comment: Hey! The image is very low-resolution and hard to read. It'd be helpful if you could please include the output via a print(df)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with filtered rows and `axis=1`:

```
#test None values like Nonetype
m = df['Select Investors'].isna()
#test None values like strings
#m = df['Select Investors'].eq('None')

df.loc[m, 'Country':] = df.loc[m, 'Country':].shift(axis=1)
```